# Application insights to Log analytics customDimentions cuts stacktrace data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

Hi i am wondering why my stack trace gets cut when i'm logging it in log analytics with Application insight?

[image]

as you can see in the image i don't get the whole stack trace for some reason.

i'm logging it like this in my application:

```
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //create a dictionary to store the json string
            var customDataDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            customDataDict.Add("Exception StackTrace", e.StackTrace);

            // Send the exception telemetry:
            telemetry.TrackException(e, customDataDict);

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

My stacktrace should look like this:

> at TestAPILogging.Controllers.LoggingApiController.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestAPILogging\TestAPILogging\Controllers\LoggingApiController.cs:line 43

Am I missing something? is there a limit in how many characters can be saved?

Answer (score 0):

Although [there are size limits](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/application-insights-limits.md), I assume this is not the case. 
Projecting query result to a online grid might truncate some long records

Data might be there, but you have to query, project or export it to be sure.